# Discord.js access Discord.Client instance from a command file

Tags: discord, discord.js

Index.js:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
require(`./commands/myCommand.js`);
```

commands/myCommand.js:

```
[some code that uses the client const]
```

How do I access the `client` `const` from my command file?

Comment: Please add your relevant code in the question, not a link to the code. If that github repo gets updated or changed, the link will no longer be useful for anyone looking at your question.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would probably be to just get the client object from `message.client`.

You could also pass the client object as a parameter when calling the commands `execute` function in index.js
`command.execute(client, message, args)`

[Permalink](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/9085788201279bbba6ede0c6e522d1e4422ca777/code_samples/command-handling/adding-features/index.js)